# Getting error 113 in Hikvision camera integration

Tags: hikvision

I am using Device Hikvision sdk for NVR , some command of API(NET_DVR_GetDVRConfig) is working but some command are showing error 113 ( Failed to load the HCGeneralCfgMgr COM ).I used this command(NET_DVR_GET_IPPARACFG_V40) but I am getting error 113. I want to know what this message mean either my camera does not support or I am doing something wrong?.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether SDK's related libraries are loaded to yourprocces